# Siri, change language recognition by Swift, dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, siri, watchos-6

I'm working on an translation APP  on WatchOS. I'd like to know how to set siri to "listen" to a certain language and change it along with a choice from the user.
For example. The user picks the italian flag? Siri sets itself to recieve Italian dictation and transcribe it. The user picks the english flag? Siri goes on english mode and trascribes it and so on.

Hope you can help, I'd normally use speech but we don't have it on watchos.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to change the language of an SFSpeechRecognizer.

```swift
let locale = Locale(identifier: "nl_NL")
SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: locale)
```

This will now listen for and transcribe Dutch words.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/recognizing_speech_in_live_audio) is more information on live speech recognition which explains how to use SFSpeechRecognizer.

See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html) document for more information on identifiers.

Comment: Any alternative solutions?

Comment: Well, it's the users' choice what language they use Siri with. If they don't like their current language they change it. I don't think your app does have anything to do with that. (not trying to be mean, it's just not the task of your app to decide this for your users) Imagine a notes app telling you "Hey you should change your language for Siri." That's not the reason someone downloaded it.

Comment: Yup. You're totally right. The main problem i'm getting is picking an original language, translate, and then recieve the text as another language ad I totally don't know how to deal with it. The dictation in watchos only works along with siri amr?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you want to use Siri or just speech recognition. In case you wanna use Siri, I wouldn't know how localization works with app extensions. In case you wanna use speech recognition, it's possible to change the language. It might be tricky to parse any language in your app though. (if you're performing actions based on it)

Comment: Pardon moi 4 my ignorance. I want to use the speech recognition, and i Tought it was what u tap on a textfield and you record your voice. Is there any specific function?

Comment: Updated the answer. There is much more to speech recognition, but this is the key part for localization.

Comment: In watch OS we don't have Speech :<

Comment: Does this help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619574-presenttextinputcontrollerwithsu ?

Comment: I can't understand why sweiftui doesn't recognizes it.